# Foreach operation in Spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a file and concatenate each line in a string, Below is the code:

```
var str:string

val RDD1 = sc.textFile("file_path").foreach{line => 
str += line
Println (str)             // prints string one by one after concatenation
}

Println(str)                // empty string
```

all the lines from a input file gets concatenated  in string which i checked using Println statement in foreach itself. 
But when i print the string variable outside foreach it is empty. 
any reason for this? ideally it should be printed with the populated value.

2. One more question, what in case if i use .map instead of .foreach in above code. when i tried in this case nothing is populated in string even println statement within .map code prints out empty. My understanding is map should also work in this case?

thanks in advance

Comment: The question is poorly designed. The code you provide won't compile as is. Please try to take some time to make some investigation on your own and at least try to make it run. Otherwise the question will probably be closed or ignored.

Comment: There's a separate copy of the  var `str` on every worker, and it's not sent back. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/29418504/21755. Really, this should be obvious - Spark's entire point is to distribute work across multiple workers, and sharing some mutable global variable like this would kill any efficiency gains.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are newbie in spark,so first learn about [spark](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_core_programming.htm) concept like transformation (map,flatmap,reduceby....), action(collect,take..) than implement the code.

your scenario is invalid but you want concatenation all line,this code will help you

```
val rddOfString = sc.textFile("file_path").map{
line => 
(1,line)//add unique key on each line
}.reduceByKey(_+_)//use reduce by for concatenation all lines
.map(_._2)//select your concat string
.collect//collect your data
```

You will get array of String,where first index contain your output

```
val str=rddOfString(0)
```

Comment: Don't `(_+_)` with Strings.

Comment: @Gabber: thanks for the code, for me it worked but using str = rddOfString.first() and not rddOfString(0). and  yes i am new to spark but i have basic understanding regarding transformation like foreach and map, the reason for this question was with foreach also it should work as foreach works on each parameter which is line in this case.

Comment: @yuvrajrajpurohit did you read my comment? It won't work as you can't have a mutable value shared across workers like that.

Comment: @zero may ask u,why ?

Comment: @yuvrajrajpurohit rddOfString is the array of string,u can get with ur output first as well as rdd(0),however if answer is acceptable plz accept it

Comment: Because iterative string concatenation on JVM is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @zero ur right,but scenario is not valid

Comment: i mean no one want concat all line.